# Why HAProxy returns 503 Service Unavailable even if some servers are available?

Tags: haproxy, high-availability

I have 10 servers behind a HAProxy load balancer. This morning **I updated and rebooted only half of the servers** (5 servers). **The other servers was still functional**. I expected HAProxy to send the requests to the available servers (it also has health checks enabled).

However **HAProxy returned some 503 errors**. How is that possible? Can I change some configuration to avoid that?

Comment: Show your configs and relevant logs.